# Celery task log using google-cloud-logging

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, celery, google-cloud-logging

I'm currently managing my API using Celery tasks and a kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Platform.

Celery is automatically logging input and output of each task. This is something I want but I would like to use the possibility of google-cloud-logging to log input and output as `jsonPayload`.

I use for all other log the following:

```py
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
from google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers import setup_logging

# Imports the Cloud Logging client library
import google.cloud.logging

# Instantiates a client
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()

handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client)
setup_logging(handler)

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

data_dict = {"my": "data"}
logger.info("this is an example", extra={"json_fields": data_dict})
```

And I use Celery with the following template:

```py
app = Celery(**my_params)

@app.task
def task_test(data):
    # Update dictonary with new data
    data["key1"] = "value1"
    return data

...

detection_task = celery.signature('tasks.task_test', args=([[{"hello": "world"}]]))
r = detection_task.apply_async()
data = r.get()
```

Here's an example of log I receive from Celery:
[image]

The blurred part correspond to the dict/json I would like to have in a jsonPayload instead of a textPayload.
(Also note that this log is marked as error on GCP but INFO from celery)

Any idea how I could connect python built-in logging, celery logger and gcp logger ?

Comment: Can you clarify _"connect python built-in logging, celery logger and gcp logger"_? I'm not sure how/why will you connect three different loggers

Comment: @AbhinavMathur "connect" is probably not the right word. But now with google-cloud-logging, we can use the build-in python logger to log trough GCP by adding a handler to the built-in logger

Comment: And by "connecting" the three logger, I could only use python build-in logger to log to GCP with jsonPayloads

Comment: Basically, you want to pass/set the Python logger in GCP and Celery loggers?

Comment: Yes I think that's it

Answer (score 0):

To connect your Python logger with GCP Logger:

```py
import logging
import google.cloud.logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler, setup_logging

client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client, name="your_log_name")
cloud_logger = logging.getLogger('cloudLogger')
# configure cloud_logger
cloud_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

To connect this logger to Celery's logger:

```py
def initialize_log(logger=None,loglevel=logging.DEBUG, **kwargs):
    logger = logging.getLogger('celery')
    handler = # use GCP handler defined above
    handler.setLevel(loglevel)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

from celery.signals import after_setup_task_logger
after_setup_task_logger.connect(initialize_log)
from celery.signals import after_setup_logger
after_setup_logger.connect(initialize_log)
```

Comment: Here are the docs for CloudLoggingHandler:
https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/logging/latest/google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler

In the docs it states that this handler is only used when not in GAE or GKE environment.