# Setting up Celery logging with GCP Cloud logging

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, logging, celery

I'm trying to get Celery task logs in my GCP Cloud logging. Although I see global Celery logs in GCP Cloud logging, logs emitted from within a `celery.task` don't show up on GCP.

Here's my current code:

```py
celery = Celery(__name__, broker=redis.url, backend=redis.url)
celery.conf.update(worker_hijack_root_logger=False)

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
gcp_cloud_logging_client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
ch = gcp_cloud_logging_client.get_default_handler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info('Successfully set up cloud logging')

# tasks
@celery.task
def celery_hello_world():
    logger.info('Hello from hello-world task!')
    task_logger = get_task_logger('hello')
    task_logger.info('hello from task logger!')
    return True
```

Then I start my Celery worker like so

```bash
celery -A app.main.celery worker --loglevel=info -B
```

In my console logs I see the following output when the task is triggered

```
[2023-03-15 03:22:47,541: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] app.main.celery_hello_world[d0c997cc-406b-4b61-b3ca-36bad5c3f005]: hello from task logger!
```

So I don't see the output from the Python logger. But neither logs end up on GCP Cloud logging...

I can change things so that I can see both Python and task logger output in the console by adding the following, after intializing Cloud logging:

```py
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-5.5s] [%(name)-12.12s]: %(message)s')
sh.setFormatter(formatter)
sh.setLevel(log_level)
root_logger.addHandler(sh)
```

This gives me the following logs in console (stdout)

```
2023-03-15 03:33:54,806 [INFO ] [celery.worke]: Connected to redis://10.163.59.219:6379/0
2023-03-15 03:33:54,816 [INFO ] [celery.worke]: mingle: searching for neighbors
2023-03-15 03:33:55,831 [INFO ] [celery.worke]: mingle: all alone
2023-03-15 03:33:55,852 [INFO ] [celery.apps.]: celery@17eae43fe194 ready.
2023-03-15 03:33:57,350 [INFO ] [celery.beat ]: beat: Starting...
2023-03-15 03:34:03,192 [INFO ] [celery.worke]: Task app.main.celery_hello_world[884768ce-5c1f-4458-99fa-5f6d9e617a17] received
2023-03-15 03:34:03,195 [INFO ] [app.main    ]: Hello from hello-world task!
[2023-03-15 03:34:03,195: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] app.main.celery_hello_world[884768ce-5c1f-4458-99fa-5f6d9e617a17]: hello from task logger!
2023-03-15 03:34:03,200 [INFO ] [celery.app.t]: Task app.main.celery_hello_world[884768ce-5c1f-4458-99fa-5f6d9e617a17] succeeded in 0.005157089002750581s: True
```

Still, I only see the following log on Cloud logging:

```
Task app.main.celery_hello_world[4d4e19ad-a1fa-4d4d-b91e-f39a1ba253a5] received
```

Can anyone see through all of this? Very much appreciated.

Note that I'm running this as part of FastAPI (same file), and all logs from FastAPI get pushed to GCP Cloud logging without issue.

Comment: Form the [***celery documentation***](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.log.html) we found that you need to pass your log file for setup_handler object ref: setup_handlers(logger, logfile, format, colorize, formatter=<class 'celery.utils.log.ColorFormatter'>, **kwargs) also can you let us know where you are running your python application.

Comment: And from the above task definition we can see that you simply passing hello world and it is getting printed successfully.

Comment: Hi there - Yes, I can print stuff to console no problem. The issue is the logging to GCP Cloud logging. I'm running this setup on a GCP VM, inside a Docker container.

Comment: I was having the same issue, and this answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72259294/20151143