# GCP Logging not working inside Celery task

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, logging, celery

I'm trying to use GCP logging inside a celery task, but it doesn't emit the logs to GCP Logs Explorer, it only outputs the logs on the console running the celery app. A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75740335/setting-up-celery-logging-with-gcp-cloud-logging), but no answer yet. Here is my code:

```
from check_attributes import list_attributes
from celery import Celery
import json


# GCP Logging
import google.cloud.logging
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.setup_logging()
import logging


# list_attributes(logging.getLogger())
logging.info('OUTSIDE Task')

app = Celery('celery_tasks', backend='redis://localhost//0', broker='redis://localhost//1')

@app.task
def dummyFunc(firstArg, secondArg):
    
    
    logging.info('INSIDE Task!!!')
    # list_attributes(logging.getLogger())
    
    result = {
                'sum' : firstArg + secondArg,
                'id': 15 
    }
```

Command used to run the celery worker:

```
celery -A celery_tasks worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info
```

> logging.info('OUTSIDE Task')

emits the message to GCP logs, but when the task is executed, instead of pushing up

> "INSIDE Task"

message,

> "OUTSIDE Task"

message is pushed again.

[image]

if I print attributes of the loggers inside and outside the task, here is what I get.

Outside the Task:

> **dict**  :  {'filters': [], 'name': 'root', 'level': 20, 'parent': None, 'propagate': True, 'handlers': [<CloudLoggingHandler 
> (NOTSET)>], 'disabled': False, '_cache': {}}
> **doc**  :
> A root logger is not that different to any other logger, except that
> it must have a logging level and there is only one instance of it in
> the hierarchy.
>
> **module**  :  logging
> **weakref**  :  None
> _cache  :  {} disabled  :  False filters  :  [] handlers  :  [<CloudLoggingHandler  (NOTSET)>] level  :  20 manager  :
> <logging.Manager object at 0x7fde273cf8b0> name  :  root parent  :
> None propagate  :  True root  :  <RootLogger root (INFO)>

Inside the Task:

> [2023-08-18 16:51:07,465: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] **module**
> [2023-08-18 16:51:07,466: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18
> 16:51:07,466: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,466:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,466:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] logging [2023-08-18 16:51:07,466:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] **weakref** [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] None [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] _cache [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] {20: True} [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] disabled [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,467:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] False [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] filters [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] [] [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] handlers [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] [<StreamHandler  (NOTSET)>]
> [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] level [2023-08-18
> 16:51:07,468: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 20 [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] manager [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,468:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,469:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] <logging.Manager object at 0x7f23044f1960>
> [2023-08-18 16:51:07,469: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] name [2023-08-18
> 16:51:07,469: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,469:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,470:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,470:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] root [2023-08-18 16:51:07,470:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] parent [2023-08-18 16:51:07,470:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,470:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,471:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,471:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] None [2023-08-18 16:51:07,471:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] propagate [2023-08-18 16:51:07,471:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,472:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,472:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,472:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] True [2023-08-18 16:51:07,472:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] root [2023-08-18 16:51:07,472:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,472:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]  :  [2023-08-18 16:51:07,472:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1]   [2023-08-18 16:51:07,475:
> WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] <RootLogger root (INFO)>

Answer (score 0):

I also find the same problem when working with Google Cloud Logging.

to fix it, should use `custom class` based CloudLoggingHandler and set transport class to `SyncTransport`

```
from google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers.transports import SyncTransport


class CustomCloudLoggingHandler(CloudLoggingHandler):

    def __init__(
            self,
            client,
            *,
            name=DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME,
            transport=SyncTransport,
            resource=None,
            labels=None,
            stream=None,
    ):
        super(CloudLoggingHandler, self).__init__(stream)
        if not resource:
            # infer the correct monitored resource from the local environment
            resource = detect_resource(client.project)
        self.name = name
        self.client = client
        self.transport = transport(client, name, resource=resource)
        self.project_id = client.project
        self.resource = resource
        self.labels = labels
        # add extra keys to log record
        log_filter = CloudLoggingFilter(project=self.project_id, default_labels=labels)
        self.addFilter(log_filter)
```

make sure to set the the new logger class loaded properly for celery